# Skdate Custom PHP Page

Tags: php, html, smarty

I am new to skadate (Dating Script) .. I want to know there is a way to create custom PHP Page in SkaDate so I can add some php and HTML code there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even [google](http://www.skadate.com/vtutorial/custom_page_creation_video_tutorial.html) it?

Comment: Yes! but not found any solution ... SkaDate have tutorial for Creating custom HTML code but I want create a Events Calendar so, I need PHP

Comment: `Events - Allows members to submit events with photo and description. Calendar/list display modes.` What is wrong with the SkaDate provided calendar?

Comment: Actually, I am unable to found the calendar in admin where it is? I can see Events Calender files in script but unable to active it... can you please let me know, how to?

Comment: Well, that's up to you now. Maybe you chose not to install them when setting up your site?

Comment: what you want to do with custom php page?